# MVC controller with 2 parameters for filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

When "mens" is passed into the URL(http://localhost:62498/Apparel/Mens), it renders the model with mens apparel. There are many items on the page, which I would like to filter. My question is, how can I add another query string into the URL to filter which specific items I want to view? For example, if I want to filter only the sale items, I want the URL to handle the model for something like http://localhost:3000/Apparel/Mens?type=Sale to display on the men's sale items.

Answer (score 0):

"Mens" isn't really an id and I think it would be helpful for you to use an attribute route like this:

```
[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{category?}")]
public ActionResult Apparel(string category = "", [FromQuery] string type = "")
```

It's quite similar to the MVC default route, but it gives a better name for the category.
The `[FromQuery]` on `type` is optional, it takes it from query string by default any way.

More on attribute routes: https://joonasw.net/view/attribute-routing-cheat-sheet-for-aspnet-core

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer to use Enum for the type.

```
if (type== EnumType.Sale){

}
else if (type == EnumType.Latest){

}
```